# PHP, Last character of string goes onto new line

Tags: php

My issue is coming from when i attach the last character to a string like so:

```
$cookie = $cookie . ";";
```

The ';' goes onto a new line when i place it into a .txt file.

If anyone knows how to make the last character attatch the the first line please let me know aha.

Comment: This means that `$cookie` already __has__ a new line. `Trim` it then.

Comment: What is in your $cookie variable?

Comment: `$cookie = trim($cookie) . ";";`

Answer (score 0):

I would may be `Trim` it

```
$cookie = trim($cookie) . ";";
```

Comment: trim() works but since it's to the right, I would go for rtrim().